# How to install locale only if that is not exist yet

Tags: locale

I want to set a locale, but it failed.

```
$ sudo update-locale  LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
```

To use the locale I installed the locale by `locale-gen`

```
$ sudo locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  ja_JP.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
$ sudo update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
$
```

Now I want to write a shell script to configure it.
How can I know which locale is already installed so that I can avoid regenerate the locale?

Answer (score 2):

I found a option `-a` that returns all locals in system.

I could check the existence of the locale by this code.

```
if [ `locale -a | grep -c ja_JP.utf` -ge 1 ]; then echo exist; else echo not exist; fi
```

Comment: You could simply use `locale -a | grep ja_JP.utf && sudo update-locale  LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8`, or `if locale -a | grep ja_JP.utf; then ...`